# Set constrain for values before saving it into firebase using flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to set constrain for the values for example if the age is less than 40 I want to show dialog for the user that the age is not appropriate and I don't want the value to be updated in firebase.

This is my code:

```
onChanged: (newValue) {
          try {
            setState(() {
              _updatedAgeS = newValue;
            });

            _updatedAge = double.parse(_updatedAgeS);
          } catch (e) {
            if (_updatedAge <= 40 || _updatedAge > 110)
              msg = "Age is not valid";
            else
              msg = "Please enter valid values";
          }
        },
        onPreesed: () async {
          final updatedUserAge = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(widget.elderlyId)
              .update({'elderlyAge': _updatedAge});
          showDialog<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return getAlert(msg);
            },
          );
        },
 Widget getAlert(String text) {
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: white,
      content: Text(
        text,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: textStyle1,
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Buttons(
            height: 35,
            width: 100,
            textColor: nave,
            text: 'close',
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `if` statement.
For example:

```
onPressed: () async {
 if (age < 40){
  // show some alert that tells the user that the age is
  // not valid
 } else {
  // update the age in firestore
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Backend validation:

Set up firebase rules for this collection so it allow update/ create if field value is less than 40:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /users/{uid} {
      allow create, update: request.resource.data.nameOfTheField > 40;
 }}}
```

after that you do validation in your app as you were answered already.